# how to get all the events of the day in angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-calendar

Is there any option in **angular-bootstrap-calendar** to grab the day's  with `on-timespan-click = "dateClicked(eventsOfTheDay)"`

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('calendarCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.calendarView = 'month';
      $scope.calendarDate = new Date();
      $scope.bookings = [{
        title: 'Today',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 1),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 2),
        recursOn: 'month',

        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 11, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 11, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }];

      $scope.bookingClicked = function(theBooking) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("This is your booking you clicked");
        console.log(theBooking);
      };

      $scope.dateClicked = function(todaysBooking) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("hello mate");
        console.log(todaysBooking);
        alert(todaysBooking);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.4/interact.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<script src="helpers.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="calendarCtrl" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{calendarTitle}}</h1>
      <mwl-calendar view="calendarView" view-date="calendarDate" events="bookings" on-event-click="bookingClicked(calendarEvent)" view-title="calendarTitle" on-timespan-click="dateClicked(eventsOfTheDay)" on-event-times-changed="calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
      edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'" delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'" on-edit-event-click="eventEdited(calendarEvent)" on-delete-event-click="eventDeleted(calendarEvent)" cell-is-open="true">
      </mwl-calendar>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @valarmorghulis  Thanks for your comment,  proper solution got from its official page https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues/281#issuecomment-182480215

Answer (score 0):

It is simply possible with `on-timespan-click="dateClicked(calendarCell.events)"` [reference](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues/281#issuecomment-182480215)

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('calendarCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.calendarView = 'month';
      $scope.calendarDate = new Date();
      $scope.bookings = [{
        title: 'Today',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 1),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 2),
        recursOn: 'month',

        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 10, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }, {
        title: 'Today is saturday',
        type: 'info',
        startsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 11, 3),
        endsAt: new Date(2016, 2, 11, 4),
        editable: false,
        deletable: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        incrementsBadgeTotal: true,
        recursOn: 'month',
        cssClass: 'a-css-class-name'
      }];

      $scope.bookingClicked = function(theBooking) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("This is your booking you clicked");
        console.log(theBooking);
      };

      $scope.dateClicked = function(todaysBooking) {
        console.clear();
        console.log("hello mate");
        console.log(todaysBooking);
        alert(todaysBooking.length);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.4/interact.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<script src="helpers.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="calendarCtrl" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{calendarTitle}}</h1>
      <mwl-calendar view="calendarView" view-date="calendarDate" events="bookings" on-event-click="bookingClicked(calendarEvent)" view-title="calendarTitle" on-timespan-click="dateClicked(calendarCell.events)" on-event-times-changed="calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
      edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'" delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'" on-edit-event-click="eventEdited(calendarEvent)" on-delete-event-click="eventDeleted(calendarEvent)" cell-is-open="true">
      </mwl-calendar>
    </div>
  </div>
```